# Custom drag on div

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net-mvc

I am need of a custom drag on div as the title suggests.
The idea is to have a panel like the img below.

[image: example map]

1. The whole area needs to be draggable.
2. The white blocks, as showed need to have different sizes, but I think this is irelevant for this matter
3. The white blocks will be loaded as needed when the user "drags" in any direction (i will be using ajax for this)
4. Will be using ASP.NET MVC for the website and jQuery

The purpose is to implement a custom map for an academic game project.
I do not need any final solution. Any hint or tip will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Are you stuck somewhere? Do you have a prototype of some type?

Comment: No prototype yet as I am stuck to come up with something that allows me to scroll the content's of the container div.

Comment: So do the white boxes need to be draggable? The title says so, but your description does not

Comment: The whole area needs to be draggable. The white boxes should follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a container, make that draggable with jquery ui and then add boxes inside it

https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

https://jsfiddle.net/ytxedata/4/

HTML

```
<div id="draggable">
    <div class="box" style="left:10px;top:10px;width:50px;height:60px;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="left:80px;top:40px;width:65px;height:45px;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="left:150px;top:70px;width:50px;height:70px;"></div>
    <div class="box" style="left:220px;top:10px;width:60px;height:30px;"></div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
});
```

CSS

```
#draggable {
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:blue;
    position:relative;
}

.box {
    background-color:red;
    position:absolute;
}
```

**EDIT:**

To add more boxes from that example you could use:

```
function addBox(x, y, w, h) {
    x = (x === 0) ? '0' : x + 'px';
    y = (y === 0) ? '0' : y + 'px';
    w = (w === 0) ? '0' : w + 'px';
    h = (h === 0) ? '0' : h + 'px';
    var $boxes = $('#draggable .box');
    var $newBox = $('<div class="box"></div>');
    $newBox.css({ 'left': x, 'top': y, 'width': w, 'height': h });
    if ($boxes.length === 0)
        $('#draggable').html($newBox);
    else
        $newBox.insertBefore($boxes.first())
}

addBox(10, 120, 100, 60);
```

Comment: That draggable area needs to fill the whole client area at all times.
When the drag event occurs, do I need to recalculate it's width/height?

Comment: @HelderMPinhal Yes, you can set its new left, top, width and height using jquery `css` function, which can be called on draggable stop event: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events

Comment: Thanks for your help and example.
Regarding the set of the css properties, wouldn't that restore the area to its original state rather than allowing the user to keep dragging the are to look for new boxes?

Comment: @HelderMPinhal I'm not sure I understand. You can use either the drag or stop event depending on your use, and set the left and top to whatever you want (0 if you want it to fill a parent, or the page)

Comment: In this fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/tic84/ytxedata/2/), which is a copy of your example with a few tweeks, the draggable area starts with the full size of the client but when I drag it, I would like it to still fit the client area and show the new content to where we dragged.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery ui draggable

```
$( "#draggable" ).draggable()
```

Also use its events to use ajax

```
 $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
  start: function() {
  //if data is not already getten 
  //some ajax code in there
  }
});
```

[For more information](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/)